# Как применить к массиву inverse_transform?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Имею:

```py
train_x = df_train[cols]
test_x = df_test[cols]
train_y = df_train['SalePrice']

saleprice_scaled = StandardScaler().fit_transform(train_y[:,np.newaxis]);

pred_model.fit(train_x, saleprice_scaled)

predicted_prices = pred_model.predict(test_x)
```

Получаю массив:

```
array([-0.63068705, -0.46680173,  0.09475258, ..., -0.31903422,
       -0.91872981,  0.66107928])
```

Как применить к нему `inverse_transform`?

```py
saleprice_scaled_reversed = StandardScaler().inverse_transform(predicted_prices)
```

Даёт ошибку:

> NotFittedError: This StandardScaler instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых нет смысла скалировать / нормализовать искомый(ые) переменные. Калибровать нужно «входные» признаки - X. Предсказываемые столбцы (Y) - калибровать бессмысленно.

Во-вторых, для того чтобы иметь возможность сделать обратное преобразование нужно сохранить объект `StandardScaler()` после обучения (`.fit()` или `.fit_transform()`) - в вашем коде он теряется после вызова `.fit_transform()`.

Сохранить объект можно так:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
saleprice_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(train_y[:,np.newaxis])
...
saleprice_scaled_reversed = scaler.inverse_transform(predicted_prices)
```

PS но лучше не скалировать искомый `Y` вообще.

Comment: Верно. Я понял свою ошибку. Калибровка необходима внутри ОПОРНЫХ данных. 
Интересно тогда, что точность предикта возросла.